# How can i change number of days in a month for Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

The problem is Persian (Iranian) months are different from Georgian months, for example 7th month of year is Mehr in Iranian Calendar and is 30 days, but July is 31 (7th month of Georgians).

Is there a way to change `Date()` object (change number of days) in javascript or something similar to get fullcalendar act like a Persian calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

things like this you are best to google first

[Persian Calendar Picker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Persian_Date_Picker.aspx)

or

[Persian Date()](http://intldate.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't want a date picker i want a javascript Date() object but act like presian calendar

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript extensions would be good at this. Please refer the following links which has explanation as well as the source:

http://intldate.codeplex.com/

In jQuery

http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html